# forkbomb, no child processes, Resource temporarily unavailable. wait() function needed

Tags: c, bash, fork, wait

I have a program that works perfectly in any online c compiler but when I put it in my college's server, it fills up with this error and I have to have the system admin stop the process because I don't have the authority to. two times is embarrassing, I can't make it three. This is the error

```
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

And here is my code. I believe my issue lies within lines 40-44, and I should add a wait but I tried NULL and &x as the pointer for the wait and neither do anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXPROCESS 8

struct userProcess {
    pid_t pid;
    int processes[2];
};

struct userProcess numProcess[MAXPROCESS];

void fork_Function(struct userProcess *, int, float);
float parent_Function(struct userProcess *, int, float);
float FofX(float);

int N = 8;

int main(void) {

    int x, y, i, status;
    int hasPrinted = 0;
    float a = 0.0;
    float b = 2.0;
    int n = 64;
    float h = (b - a) / n;

    numProcess[0].pid = getpid();

    for (x = 0; x <= MAXPROCESS; x++) {
        pipe(numProcess[x].processes);
        numProcess[x].pid = fork();
    }

    // process through each function and call the fork_Function
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        if (numProcess[i].pid == 0) {
            fork_Function(numProcess, i, h);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    double result = parent_Function(numProcess, N, h);
    printf("\nThe Trapezoidal Rule Result: %f", result);
    exit(0);
}

// function executed by the child process
void fork_Function(struct userProcess x[], int count, float trapBase) {

    float threadIN[2], threadOUT[2] = { 0, count };
    read(x[count].processes[0], threadIN, sizeof(double));
    
    int c = 0;
    while (c < N) {
        threadOUT[0] = trapBase *(threadIN[0] + threadIN[1]) / 2.0;
        write(x[0].processes[1], threadOUT, sizeof(double));
        read(x[count].processes[0], threadIN, sizeof(double));
        c++;
    }
}

// function executed by the parent
float parent_Function(struct userProcess x[], int N, float trapBase) {
    
    float threadIN[2], threadOUT[2];
    int y = 0;
    float integral = 0;

    for (y = 0; y < N; y++) {
        threadOUT[0] = FofX(trapBase *(float)(y));
        threadOUT[1] = FofX(trapBase *(float)(y + 1));
        write(x[y + 1].processes[1], threadOUT, sizeof(double));
    }
    for (y = N; y < 64; y++) {
        read(x[0].processes[0], threadIN, sizeof(double));
        integral += threadIN[0];
        threadOUT[0] = FofX(trapBase *(float)(y));
        threadOUT[1] = FofX(trapBase *(float)(y + 1));
        write(x[(y % 8) + 1].processes[1], threadOUT, sizeof(double));
    }
    return integral;
}

float FofX(float x) {
    return 1 / ((x * x) + 1);
}
```

EDIT: I updated the code to get rid of the useless if, that second for loop and the while loop only goes for the length of the amount of processes. I ran this in an online compiler and it worked perfectly. But I do not think I fixed the forking issues

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `numProcess[MAXPROCESS]` means that the maximum index into the array is `MAXPROCESS - 1`.  Iterating with `for (x = 1; x <= MAXPROCESS; x++) { numProcess[x].pid = fork(); }` exceeds that max.

Comment: You should use the usual idiom and do `for(x = 0; x < MAXPROCESS...`

Comment: The `if(getpid() == numProcesses[0].pid)` accomplishes nothing because it's only run by the parent, where the test is true.  Your `fork()` loop is *inside* the `if` and so *every* child that's forked will continue running the loop and forking its own children.   You will wind up with not 8 processes but instead 256.

Comment: `wait()` is pointless with your program as it stands; its purpose is to clean up after a child exits, but your child processes never exit because `fork_Function` is an infinite loop.  Is that intentional?  They won't even get killed by SIGPIPE when the parent exits, because all the other children still have the read ends of all the pipes opened (which is another bug).

Comment: `numProcess[x].pid = fork();` -- Where do you expect the child process to start executing from?

Comment: After `numProcess[i].pid = fork();`, add `if (numProcess[i].pid == 0) {` `fork_Function(numProcess, i, h);` `exit(0);` `}` otherwise the child processes are created exponentially by the loop. You can get rid of the other loop that calls `fork_Function`. Also, the `for` loop control should be `for (i = 0; i < MAXPROCESS; i++) {` to avoid out-of-bounds access to `numProcess[MAXPROCESS]`.

Comment: I just edited the code to what I have now. I still don't think I fixed the main issue but my code is more efficient now!